# Fortran transfer function gets different value from source data

Tags: fortran

I would like to achieve the following target:

> Use the pointer of first element of a self defined type data (say A) to refer A

I created the following prototype of codes:

```
program test

    implicit none

    type foo
        integer i
        integer j
    end type foo

    type(foo), target :: a
    type(foo) b
    integer, pointer :: ai

    a%i = 1
    a%j = 2

    ai => a%i

    print *, "Address of a is", loc(a)

    b = transfer(ai, b)

    print *, "The values of a are:", a%i, a%j

    print *, "Address of b is", loc(b)

    print *, "The values of b are:", b%i, b%j

end program test
```

I expect the values of `b` should be equal with `a`, but I got the result in my computer as

```
Address of a is      140736918227392
The values of a are:           1           2
Address of b is      140736918227376
The values of b are:           1           0
```

Where the value of `b%j` is different from `a%j`. What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
My purpose is to hide a defined type (say `foo`) from user, and only let user access the first part of `foo` (say an array), and when user provides that array, I can get the rest part of `foo`. It is sorts of encapsulation. User can be freed from the typing of "%".

Comment: I think `transfer` only transfer the content of `a%i`, and for the rest of the content of type `foo` for `b`, undefined value is filled in. So is there any function that can access the content of `a%i`.

Comment: Could I call `memcpy` in Fortran?

Comment: Yes, if you link with a standard C library (so almost always). Why would you want to do that?

Comment: With a proper interface you can call any C function.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that you've understood what the `transfer` function does.  The statement

```
b = transfer(ai, b)
```

takes the data found in location `ai` and creates a copy of it with the type (and kind if relevant) of `b`.  So `transfer` is used to allow a program to, for example, treat the bits of a real number as if they were the bits of an integer.  What your statement does is to take the data found at `ai`, which is an integer, and change it to a value of `type(foo)`, and assign that to `b`.

I think you got lucky in as much as the compiler didn't complain that the value of `ai` didn't provide `transfer` with enough bits to populate `b`.  I'm not surprised, since `transfer` is essentially a way of circumventing Fortran's strict typing.  Certainly a direct assignment such as `b = 1` causes a compilation error because the lhs and rhs don't have compatible types.

I don't think you have any right to expect the value of `b%j` to have any particular value when you come to write it out.  From my quick investigations the value of `b%j` is not modified by your program at all, in your case it is initialised to `0` and is not modified.

But I think the real problem is that you are trying to do something that no Fortran programmer would do, that is to use a pointer to the first element of a structure as a reference to the entire structure.  That smells of C and its cousins.

In Fortran it is much more natural to declare `ai` to be of `type(foo), pointer` and then write statements such as

```
ai => a
...
b = ai
```

What are you really trying to do ?  If the answer is 'program in C using a Fortran compiler' well, good luck to you and enjoy the world of pain that's barrelling down the turnpike.

Comment: +1 transfer is not memcpy and does not treat a pointer to first member as a pointer to struct.

Comment: I would like to hide the `type(foo)` (for example) from user, and only let user access the part of `type(foo)` (say the `j` in `type(foo)`). And when user provide `j`, then I can get the rest part  of `type(foo)`.

Comment: Use private components (and maybe setter/getter procedures) then.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, what

```
ai => a%i
b = transfer(ai, b)
```

does mean, when translated to C.

It is

```
b = (foo)(a->i)
```

if my remembrance of C does not fool me. So you are really converting an integer to type foo.

**--EDIT--**
 You can have many private components inside a structure (derived type), that users of the module do not see, but you can use them inside the module. The user can interact with the private entities using procedures defined in the module. With newer compilers you can even have methods (type-bound procedures) and other OOP as in C++.

```
module mod
  type foo
    private
    integer,public :: i
    integer        :: j  !is private!
  end type

end module mod

program p

  use mod

  type(foo) :: a,b

  b%i = 1
  !intrinsic assignment should work, even if you don't see a%j and b%j
  !you can also override the assignment yourself
  a = b

  write(*,*) a%i

end program p
```

Comment: Could you provide an example that can fix the example?

Comment: To get a whole struct just from the component? You can not do it  if you don't play with bad things (C pointers, sequence association or similar.)

Comment: Yes, I can bear the calling of C in Fortran. :)

Comment: That is not very clever in this case, use private components, as in C++.

Comment: See my edit above. You don't even need any pointer (but you can use one).